# L2TP iptables port forward

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, iptables, l2tp

I'm setting up port forwarding for an L2TP VPN connection to the local Windows 2003 VPN server. The router is a simpel Debian machine with iptables. The VPN server works perfect. But I cannot log in from the  WAN. I'm missing something.

The VPN server is using a pre-shared key (L2TP) and give's out an IP in the range: 192.168.3.0. Local network range is 192.168.2.0/24

I added the route: with route add -net 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.240 gw 192.168.2.13 (the vpn server)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 1701 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.13
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 1701 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 500 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.13
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 4500 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.13
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p 50 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.13
iptables -A FORWARD -p 50 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p 51 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.13
iptables -A FORWARD -p 51 -j ACCEPT
```

The whole iptables script is (without the line's from above):

```
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies

            #Flush table's
            iptables -F INPUT
            iptables -F OUTPUT
            iptables -F FORWARD
            iptables -t nat -F

            #Drop traffic
            iptables -P INPUT DROP
            iptables -P FORWARD DROP
            iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

            #verkeer naar buiten toe laten en nat aanzetten
            iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
            iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
            iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

            #RDP forward voor windows servers
            iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.10:3389
            iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
            iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3340  -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.12:3340
            iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3340 -j ACCEPT

            #toestaan SSH verkeer
            iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.1
            iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

            #toestaan verkeer loopback
            iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

            #toestaan lokaal netwerk
            iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT

            #accepteren established traffic
            iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 --match state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

        #droppen ICMP boodschappen
        iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -i eth0 -m limit --limit 10/minute -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -i eth0 -j REJECT

    ifconfig eth1 192.168.2.1/24
    ifconfig eth0 XXXXXXXXXXXXX/30
    ifconfig eth0 up
    ifconfig eth1 up
    route add default gw XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    route add -net 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.240 gw 192.168.2.13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution: iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --sport 1701 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 1):

Please run a tcpdump session while doing the test and also look at the counters from iptables -L -nv before and after the test.

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a Firewall and NAT you might be looking for:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885407/en-us

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.